# (error) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, webpack-5

I use **"static"** in the code and this error appears.

*You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.*

```
import {ExcelComponent} from '../../core/ExcelComponent';

export class Toolbar extends ExcelComponent {
  static className = 'excel__toolbar'
  toHTML() {
    return '<h1>Toobar</h1>'
  }
}
```

Installed **@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties** but it didn't help.

Webpack config:

```
const jsLoaders = () => {
  const loaders = [
    {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'],
      },
    }]

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          },
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: jsLoaders(),
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was elsewhere. The @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties works well.